# Call a variable from my $profile script at the console

Tags: powershell

My $profile script starts a transcript whenever it is run. I am piping the output of Start-Transcript to a variable ($log) like so:
Start-Transcript -path $logFile -append > $global:log

I would like to be able to read this variable from the console. As you can see I tried explicitly setting the $log variable scope to Global (it didn't work).

For instance I would like to be able to run the following command:
notepad $log1

And have the transcript open in notepad.

Is this even possible? I've been running amok in Google for about an hour, and I can't find anything with relevance to this (which probably means it can't be done, but I figured I'd ask anyway).

Alternatively, is there a way to get the path to the current transcript file some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that redirection works. Why not just do `notepad $logFile`?

Update: AFAIK, There is no way you can find the Start-Transcript Path value. However, you can find if the session is getting transcribed or not. Check this: http://poshcode.org/1500

**If you do not specify a path, Start-Transcript uses the path in the value of the $Transcript global variable. If you have not created this variable, Start-Transcript stores the transcripts in the $Home\My Documents directory as \PowerShell_transcript..txt files.**

BTW, as a recommended practice & before you start writing scripts, you should always start at the console. For example, when I run the following at PowerShell console:

```
PS C:\> $logfile = "C:\Scripts\Scratch\test.log"
PS C:\> Start-Transcript -path $logFile -append > $global:log
PS C:\> Get-Command Get-Help

CommandType     Name                                                Definition
-----------     ----                                                ----------
Cmdlet          Get-Help                                            Get-Help [[-Name] <String>] [-Path <String>] [-C...


PS C:\> Get-Variable -Name log
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'log'.
At line:1 char:13
+ Get-Variable <<<<  -Name log
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (log:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand
```

The above output at the console clearly tells me that the redirection never worked.

Comment: Your syntax to try to output to a variable is wrong, it should be " > variable:log".  However, this still will not work because redirection only works on files.

Comment: I understand that. I did not intend to output to a variable. Just wanted to show how to use console to first try out commands before putting them in a script. So, used the same lines as in the question!

Comment: I didn't know you couldn't redirect like that. It does go _somewhere_ because if that line is there, the console does not output the transcript path, whereas if I remove the "> $global:log" part, it does output the transcript path to the console when transcription is started.

I guess basically I need to know if I can access a variable that is set in my $profile script from the console. Forget what I was trying to do in the example above, the original question was ill posed.

Comment: On a side note, the syntax I used for defining that $log variable earlier ($global:log) is valid (it just wasn't being assigned to anything, because my redirection was wrong). As an explanation, if you do this:

$global:testVar = "working"

And then run:

gv testVar -valueonly

It will echo the value. The global: between the $ and the variable will explicitly define the variable's scope.

Comment: And I answered my own question ;) Thanks for reminding me of Get-Variable (I always seem to forget that one), I used it to discover that I can indeed access variables defined in my $profile script from the console. /hattip ravikanth

Comment: You don't even need to use Get-Variable, just $log will work.  BTW, the reason why "> $global:log" didn't do anything was because it was empty, so you were really doing "> ''" or possibly "> $null".

Comment: Which confuses me kinda, because the message that I was trying to redirect disappeared from the console. _Where did it go???_

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to `Tee-Object` to print out the command and save the output to a variable. Then clean up the variable to only include the filename.

```
Start-Transcript -path $logFile -append | Tee-Object -Variable log
$log = $log -split "is " | select -Last 1
```